# Does the standing wave equation proof require $\ell=Nλ$?

Tags: waves, acoustics, wavelength, superposition, harmonics

Consider two identical sources $S_1$ and $S_2$ of waves, separated by a distance $\ell$ (as shown in the figure).

[image]

The sources produce waves in opposite directions(and towards each other). Now, suppose we wish to derive the equation for the standing wave produced.

Let us take the origin at $S_1$. The equation of the wave due to $S_1$ is:-
$$ y_1=A\sin(wt-kx_1)$$
where $x_1$ is the distance from $S_1$.

Now the equation of the wave due to $S_2$ is:-
$$ y_2=A\sin(wt-kx_2)$$

where $x_2$ is the distance from $S_2$. Note that here we take $x_2>0$.

Now, applying the principle of superposition, we get:-

$$ y=y_1+y_2=A\sin(wt-kx_1)+A\sin(wt-kx_2)$$
Now, observe $x_2=\ell-x_1$, so we get:-
$$ y=y_1+y_2=A\sin(wt-kx_1)+A\sin(wt-k(\ell-x_1))=A\sin(wt-kx_1)+A\sin(wt+kx_1-k\ell)$$

Using $\sin C+\sin D=2\sin\left(\frac{C+D}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{D-C}{2}\right)$, we get:-

$$y=2A \cos\left(kx-\frac {k\ell}{2}\right)\sin\left(wt-\frac{k\ell}{2}\right)$$

Note, that here we replace $x_1$ with $x$ since $x=x_1$ as the origin is at $S_1$.

However, the standard equation of stationary waves in such a case is given as $y=2A \cos(kx)\sin(wt)$. Using the equation we just derived, $\ell$ must =Nλ (where N is a non-negative integer) so that $k\ell=\frac{2π}{λ}.Nλ=2Nπ$ and now,
$$y=2A \cos\left(kx-\frac {2Nπ}{2}\right)\sin\left(wt-\frac{2Nπ}{2}\right)=2A (-\cos(kx))(-\sin(wt))=2A\cos(kx)\sin(wt))$$ as required.

Therefore, our proof of the standard equation of stationary waves requires $\ell=Nλ$. However, looking at the proof in my textbook, there is no discussion of this and the author uses $y=y_1+y_2=A\sin(wt-kx)+A\sin(wt+kx)$. A superficial explanation is given that a wave traveling in the opposite direction is taken with a '+kx' with no deeper reasoning. Although, my proof helps explain the origin of the '+kx' term (in the wave traveling in opposite direction), it adds a rather restrictive condition i.e. $\ell=Nλ$. Thus, I am skeptical about it.

Please help me out with two things:-

1. Is my proof correct? If not, then what is the reasoning behind the '+kx'?
2. If my proof is correct, then why isn't the $\ell=Nλ$ condition more commonly seen?

Comment: Can you give a reference for the "standard equation"?

Comment: The standard equations assume that the waves are in a specific form, like the ones you've described but no x1,x2, just x. If you actually have a "source" of waves on the other side, such that they are IDENTICLE then obviously a translation like you have done must be made, in order to fit the condition that it looks like a "mirror" image on the otherside.  In which case your conclusions and equations are correct I believe. In order for it to be a mirror image you need to perform a translation such that f(x,t) =f( L,0) = 0. This is a condition that you impose given you KNOW they're mirror source

Comment: The standard equations dont really say theres a specific "source" of waves,at a fixed point, that MUST be mirror images. It just equations that say given there is 2 waves moving in opposite directions in a specific form

Comment: jensen paull is correct. The D' Alembert solution to the wave equation contains two "terms". One describes a diverging wave and the other a converging wave. Both constitute solutions to the wave equation. Think of it like considering another source at $\infty$ instead of at $x = \mathcal{l}$. What you have actually "derived" here is the necessary "boundary conditions" for a standing wave to exist. If the other source is not $N \cdot \lambda$ apart then you don't get a standing wave. When you have a "hard" boundary (or an open/free end) you virtually place a source there, which is what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ S= \sin(kx-\omega t) + \sin(kx+\omega t)$$

**First term:**

$$\sin(kx-\omega t) =$$

$$\sin(kx)\cos(-\omega t) + \cos(kx)\sin(-\omega t)$$

$$\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t) - \cos(kx)\sin(\omega t)$$

**Second term:**

$$\sin(kx+\omega t) =$$

$$\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t) + \cos(kx)\sin(\omega t)$$

Adding them up gets:

$$2\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)$$

This is the standard formula given that there are 2 waves in the form above.

**Your situation:**

You have described a different situation, in which there are 2 MIRROR sources, at a fixed distance between them.

The resulting standing wave is different as you have 2 waves in a form different than the above formula

Our first source wave moving to the right is described as:

$\sin(kx-\omega t)$

This function has a zero at $f(0,0)$

we want our secondary MIRROR source, to have the same behaviour at its location at $x=L$.

To find the corresponding wave I  will translate a standard wave moving to the left by $\gamma$.

$f_{2}(x,y) = \sin(k(x-\gamma)+\omega t)$

To match and be a mirror with the first source, the condition $f_{2}(L,0) = 0$ must be imposed

But the phase must also be accounted for, doing so with some diagrams you find that the phase must be $\pi +2n\pi$, ( to make the function zero at f(L,0))

$$\sin(k(x-\gamma)+\omega t) = f_{2}$$

$$\sin(k(L-\gamma)+\omega * 0) = 0$$

$$(k(L-\gamma)+\omega * 0)
 = \pi +2n\pi$$

$kL-k\gamma = \pi + 2n\pi$

$L-\frac{(\pi + 2n\pi)}{k} = \gamma$

Or simply

$L-\frac{\pi}{k} = \gamma$

Plugging it back into our equation

$f_{2}(x,y) = \sin(kx-kL+\pi + \omega t)$

Edit: Remember my original wave has a different form that  yours, try and see if you can do it with waves in your form! For 2 waves is this form, you get a silmar condition for the standard formula apply

Here they are the same provided
$L = n\lambda + 1/2\lambda$

Which is different than yours, but that's because I chose waves of a different form

Comment: Just to clarify, from what I understood- any two waves with same A,w,k will produce standing waves provided they are traveling in the opposite direction. So, the equation y=2Acos(kx)sin(wt) is not a general equation for a standing wave and is only an equation for a specific standing wave i.e. the one produced by superposition of sin(−) and sin(+)?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Mirror sources separated by a distance will not have waves of this form. Hence us translating one of the waves, and finding conditions on this translation, in order to "make them" mirror images.

Comment: great answer! nice edit and clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The 'standard equation' that you quote arises from this superposition of progressive waves...

$$y=y_1+y_2=A\sin(\omega t-kx)+A\sin(\omega t+kx)$$

These 'component' waves are clearly in phase at $x=0$.

*Your* 'component' waves, $y_1=A\sin(\omega t-kx_1)$ and $y_2=A\sin(\omega t-kx_2)$ are *not* in phase at $x_1=0$ for an arbitrary choice of $l=x_1+x_2$. You should therefore not expect their superposition to yield the 'standard' equation that you quote.

The equation that you have derived for *your* component waves is, I think correct. As expected it differs from the 'standard' equation by added constants in the arguments of the trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're missing boundary conditions. Anytime you want to solve partial derivative equations, you have to provide boundary conditions, or the solution is undefined.

To get a standing wave, the most commun situation is to use "strict boundary conditions", where the wave's amplitude has to be zero on both extremities. If you take $y(x,t)=2A\cos(\omega t)\cos(kx)$ with $y(0,t)=y(l,t)=0$, you naturally get the quantization condition similar to the one you mentioned.

Another possibility is "periodic boundary conditions": the wave's amplitude must be equals on both ends, but not necessarily zero.

So far it's mostly math, so choosing the proper boundary conditions is where physics starts.

Comment: You are correct in the general sense. However, in the OP's problem a "matching" boundary condition is implied at $\infty$. Nice remark though.

Comment: @ZaellixA You're right, I missed it. I'm not entirely comfortable with it, however, since $\cos$ has no defined limit at $\pm\infty$, so you can't write any boundary condition at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You did correct mathematics deriving the standing wave equation

$$y=2Acos(kx-\frac {kl}{2})sin(wt-\frac{kl}{2})$$ which comes as the superposition of

$$y_1=Asin(wt-kx)$$ and $$y_2=Asin(wt+kx-kl)$$

However the other equation of standing wave which is

$$y=2Asin(wt)cos(kx)$$

comes as the superposition of the following two wave equations

$$Y_1=Asin(wt-kx)$$ and
$$Y_2=Asin(wt+kx)$$

Notice that $y_1$ and $Y_1$ are identical whereas $y_2$ has extra phase wrt $Y_2$. The two becomes identical only when that phase difference is $N×2\pi$.

Thus
$kl$ = $N×2\pi$, which gives $$l=N\lambda$$

Now coming to your first question,
Your derivation of standing wave is correct however there is a phase difference of $kl$ between the wave you described as travelling in -ve x axis and the wave defined by just changing -kx to +kx as done by the author.

Secondly, the condition $$l=N\lambda$$ is not generally seen because it's not a necessary condition. This condition just makes $y_2$ and $Y_2$ identical.